# MIPS: take register -$t0 and -$t1 and put them in memory location x and y

Tags: mips, subtraction

> Write a MIPS program that will take the registers $t0 and $t1, and put −$t0 in memory location
>   x and −$t1 in memory location y. You should use only the instructions li , sub, and sw.

Is it possible to minus registers in MIPS? "-$t0"

I have been told that this is false: *sw $t0 x sw $t1 y* and that I should be also using sub and li to write program.

Comment: Watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3ltaJ5UU5I, or read your notes from class, then try to do the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a register named `$0` or (`$zero`) that always contains zero. So to negate another register you can just subtract it from `$zero` and store the result back to the first register:

```
sub $t0,$zero,$t0  # $t0 = 0 - $t0 == -$t0
```